# Codeigniter uploads only ony one image instead of multiple

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload multiple images using the codeigniter file upload library but it only uploads one file even when multiple are selected. Kindly assist

```
//uploading images
    public function upload_image() {
        $this->load->helper('form');

        $config = array(
            'upload_path' => "./image_uploads/",
            'allowed_types' => "jpg|png|jpeg",
            'overwrite' => TRUE,
            'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
            'max_height' => "768",
            'max_width' => "1024"
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        var_dump($_FILES); die();

        foreach ($_FILES as $key => $userfileObject) {
            if (!empty($userfileObject['name'])) {
                $this->upload->initialize($config);  
                  var_dump($_FILES['userfile']);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload($_FILES[$key])) {
                    $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
                    flashMsg($errors);
                } else {
                    // Code After Files Upload Success GOES HERE
                    $data['content'] = 'success';
                    $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
                }`enter code here`
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: it is 'Chrysanthemum'

Comment: I'm uploading files with different filenames eg. 'Desert' and 'Chrysanthemum' , it picks the last one....how can I go about it...?

Answer (score 0):

this might help where `p_image` is file name

```
if (isset($_FILES['p_image']['name'])) {
                // total files //
                $count   = count($_FILES['p_image']['name']);
                // all uploads //
                $uploads = $_FILES['p_image'];

                for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                    if ($uploads['error'][$i] == 0) {
                        move_uploaded_file($uploads['tmp_name'][$i], 'uploads/product_cover/' . $uploads['name'][$i]);

                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_FILES as $key => $userfileObject)
            { 

                if ($this->upload->do_upload($key))
                {
                    $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
                    flashMsg($errors);
                }
                else {
                // Code After Files Upload Success GOES HERE
                $data['content'] = 'success';
                $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
                }`enter code here`


            }
```